# Replacing swamp cooler pads

Tags: hvac, evaporative-cooling

I have a AercoCool Pro 4800 swamp cooler roof unit and need to get new rigid pads for it. Do the pads need be specific to the brand according to the cooler's spec sheet, or can I use any pad that is the correct dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

The pads are not a big deal you want ones that fit and are rated for the filled weight (filled weight of the revisor or tank) . If the pads are not heavy enough they will not support the unit and may cause damage to the structure.